# Specify method names sequence TestNG

Tags: testng

I am running selenium tests using `TestNG` programatically.  I want to run test methods in sequence that  i mention.

Its like attribute `preserve-order="true"` if we use for `TestNG.XML`.
Similar functionality how can i achive it without using TestNG.XMl.

`setTestNames` is not working

```
TestNG tng= new TestNG();

tng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { A.class});

//tng.setTestNames

tng.run();
```

`A.class` is having class level `@Test` specified . So all methods in that class are testcases.
So Testng executing all methods in A. I want to run in sequence as they appear in the class.

Answer (score 4):

In testNg you can use

```
@Test(priority = 1)
```

and them change this to all the methods to keep the order you want like

```
@Test(priority = 2)
@Test(priority = 3)
```

Another solution would be the use of

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" }) as stated in TestNG docs.
```

I searched TestNG docs and I cannot see an easy way to do what you want using annotatios...

Comment: But i am doing a selenium framework. So it should be generic. above approch dynamically we can't put in order of execution. But i am able to achive using IMethodInterceptor. I will take setof methods from excel sheet before implementiong IMethodInterceptor. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Without a `testng.xml`, the easiest way to do this is probably to implement your own [IMethodInterceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors).

Comment: Yes. Finally i am able to implement IMethodInterceptor. Thanks to all